# data type understanding of Parse database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, parse-platform, custom-data-type

I am developing iOs application with back-end Parse, but I have some question regarding data-type in Parse.

There is 10 datatype in parse database

[image]

Now my questions are :

*1. For foreign key I have to use Relation, then Pointer used for which purpose ?*

*2. GeoPoint used for which purpose ?*

*3. For latitude-longitude I have to select Which Data Type ?*

*4. For Image I have to use which data type ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the link your can find :
https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html